# "I first saw him in X in year Y" vs "the first time I saw him was in X in year Y" vs "the first time I saw him in X was in year Y"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I made up the sentence: "I first saw him in Spain in 1946."

Does it mean that the first time I saw him was in Spain in 1946 or that I saw him many times in Spain but the first time was in 1946?

Comment: Your text is inherently ambiguous. Maybe it means you'd seen that old friend in *other* places (not Spain) *before* 1946, or maybe the first time you ever saw him was in Spain (in 1946, not before then). Note that it's really irrelevant to speculate on what it was ***probably*** intended to mean (i.e. - which of those two meanings is ***most likely**?*) because we don't have a full context. And in fact, since the OP himself just made the sentence up, I think it's fair to say *it doesn't [yet] **have** a "meaning"*. It's just words with no context.

Comment: I first saw that dog on my lawn yesterday. I first saw [x] in [place] in [year]. is pretty straightforward. And I fail to see how "my old friend" could have become one in 1946; He  would have already been one.

Comment: If you made up the sentence you should know what it means.

Answer (score 1):

That would normally be interpreted as both place and time being modifiers of first and so meaning

> Where I first met him was Spain, and when I first met him was 1946.

To imply that you met him before your 1946 meeting in Spain, try

> The first time I met him in Spain was 1946.

To imply that you met him more than once during 1946, but the first meeting during that year was in Spain, try

> My first meeting with him during 1946 was in Spain

Answer (score 1):

"I first saw Juan in Spain in 1946" would probably mean that that was when the two of you first met. To make the other meaning clear it would have to be "The first time I saw him in Spain was in 1946."

However, using 'my old friend' seems to me to make it a bit ambiguous. Only the surrounding context would make it clear whether he was already an *old* friend in 1946, or whether your friendship dates from that time.